# Is it possible to set manual mode for formula calculation in Excel Online?

Tags: excel, ms-office

By default, the calculation mode in Excel Online is `automatic`.

I have not found how to change this to `manual` mode.

Could anyone confirm if it is impossible or possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to switch calculation modes from within Excel Online itself. It will however respect the current settings saved in that workbook.

Open the spreadsheet in Excel for Windows and switch to `manual`. From this point forward, Excel Online will use manual calculation.

To manually recalculate the workbook, switch to the Data tab and select "Calculate Workbook":

[image]